# make an array with the values of similar keys from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have an array in JSON array format. I want to extract the values of common keys and make a new array with this. 
I've tried this

```
var date = [];
var amt = [];
for(var i in data){
    date.push(data[i].sale_date);
    amt.push(data[i].total);
}
```

where `sale_date` and `total` are the keys.
but this code returned an array of undefined objects.
my array named `data` looks like

```
{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"}{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"}
```

I'm expecting two arrays `date[2017-12-26 11:05:05, 2017-12-26 11:05:18 ]` and `amt[500, 500]`
I'm getting `data` as a ajax response From the code below.

```
$sql = "SELECT sale_date, total FROM customers";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){ 
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $db_data = $row;
                print json_encode($db_data);
            }
        }
```

And this how my ajax request looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("ajax-req-handler.php",
    {
        key: "draw-line-chart"
    },
    function( data ){
        console.log(data);
        var date = [];
        var amt = [];
        for(var i in data){
            date.push(data[i].sale_date);
            amt.push(data[i].total);
        }
        console.log(date);
        console.log(amt);
     });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"}
];

var date = [];
var amt = [];
for(var i in data){
    console.log(i);
    date.push(data[i].sale_date);
    amt.push(data[i].total);
}

console.log(date);
console.log(amt);
```

PHP Code :-

```
    $sql = "SELECT sale_date, total FROM customers";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $data = array();
        if($result->num_rows>0){ 
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $db_data[] = $row;
            }
        }
   echo json_encode($db_data);
```

Ajax Request :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("ajax-req-handler.php",
{
    key: "draw-line-chart"
},
function( data ){
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var date = [];
    var amt = [];
    for(var i in data){
        date.push(data[i].sale_date);
        amt.push(data[i].total);
    }
    console.log(date);
    console.log(amt);
 });
```

});

Comment: This is exactly what I've done but only the difference is that instead of defining the array i.e data I'm getting it through an ajax response

Comment: @Waeez You will need to change your php code. The problem is with your PHP code.

Comment: oh. Thanks, I've fixed my PHP code but still getting the array of undefined objects

Comment: @Waeez Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: yes. still `date` and `amt` are the arrays of undefined objects. I also added my ajax request in my question. have a look on it

Comment: What is the output of console.log(data); ?

Comment: `[{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 05:52:31","total":"4000"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 05:16:08","total":"72000"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-20 06:50:48","total":"67640"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-27 05:26:07","total":"39957"}]`

Comment: @Waeez See updated ajax request code. You need to parse the data which is in string format to javascript array.

Comment: Hi Lalit, one more issue is there. what if I change my SQL Query to `SELECT DATE(sale_date), SUM(total) FROM customers GROUP BY DATE(sale_date)`.  It changed the array keys to `DATE(sale_date)` and `SUM(total)`. and I tried `date.push(data[i].DATE(sale_date))`. but this didn't work.

Comment: Change your query to SELECT DATE(sale_date) AS sale_date, SUM(total) AS total FROM customers GROUP BY DATE(sale_date)

Answer (score 2):

You need to encapsulate your object between array

```js
var data = [{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"}]
var date = [];
var amt = [];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    date.push(data[i].sale_date);
    amt.push(data[i].total);
}
console.log(date);
console.log(amt);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done but only the difference is that instead of defining the array i.e `data` I'm getting it through an ajax response

Comment: you are getting multiple object in your respose. so you need to encapsulate your data in array and make it array object. Kindly check your response

Answer (score 2):

This is not a JavaScript but PHP issue.... you are sending invalid JSON. The following:

```
{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"}{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"}
```

Should actually look like:

```
[{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"}]
```

You need to change your PHP code to this:

```
// Add content type so that jQuery knows you're sending JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$sql = "SELECT sale_date, total FROM customers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$db_data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $db_data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($db_data);
```

Sending `Content-Type` header should be enough but you should also change your jQuery code just to be sure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("ajax-req-handler.php", {
        key: "draw-line-chart"
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var date = [];
        var amt = [];
        for (var i in data) {
            date.push(data[i].sale_date);
            amt.push(data[i].total);
        }
        console.log(date);
        console.log(amt);
    }, "json");
    // the 4th parameter is dataType set to json
});
```

Comment: oh. Thanks, I've fixed my PHP code but still `date` and `amt` are the arrays of undefined objects

Comment: Post the code where you assign the JSON to `data` (the AJAX code).

Comment: @Waeez revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

//Hope this will be of help.

```
var data = [ {"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:05","total":"500"},{"sale_date":"2017-12-26 11:05:18","total":"500"} ];

var date = amt = [];

X = 0;

while (x < data.length) {
date.push(data[x].sale_date);
amt.push(data[x].total);
x++;
};

console.log(date);
console.log(amt);
```

**Explanation:**

line 1 is the array of objects which represent the data u are pulling from ur json data.

Line 2 is the declaration of the two variable arrays which is assigned to and empty array. So, I used the short form of declaring multi-variable on the same line of statement.

Line 3 is the initialization of the counter "x" that will help break the While Loop once the it counts to the last Object in the array "data".

Line 4. Then the While Loop which keep iterating through the array " data". The conditional statement there always check if the counter "x" is < (less than) the length of the array In each iteration it.

Line 5. In the While Loop block code using the counter "x" as index of the array to access the property "sale_date" of the object in that array index and push it to the array "date" (I.e adding it at the end of the array "date").

Line 6. The same as line 5, accessing the property total in that index of the array " data" and push it to array "amt".

Line 7 increment the counter " x" by 1 and assign it to back to x which is used to reevaluate the While Loop.

Line 8 & 9 is just a console log that displays what's in date and amt respectively.

Thanks

Hope this makes sense to u... Please, Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Could you add some documentation/explanation?

Comment: OK.. In a jiffy